# Should I be using an array or object to build a summary?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I'm building an interface that will calculate a total (based on neighboring inputs) when an input is checked. When an input is checked, I'm getting the values of the other inputs in the same `<td>` and then building a grand total.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vdunm/1/

I need to build a summary of totals (grouped by name) for all checkboxes that are checked and I just can't seem to find the right path on how to do it.

So if you were to check the first 3 rows (2 foos and 1 bar) I would want the output to look something like this:

```
FOO: 100  
BAR: 30
```

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<table id="test">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id" size="20" value="100" />
            <input type="text" name="name" size="20" value="FOO" />
            <input type="text" name="cost" size="20" value="10.00">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" size="20" value="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id" size="20" value="200" />
            <input type="text" name="name" size="20" value="BAR" />
            <input type="text" name="cost" size="20" value="10.00">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" size="20" value="3">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="id" size="20" value="300" />
            <input type="text" name="name" size="20" value="FOO" />
            <input type="text" name="cost" size="20" value="10.00">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" size="20" value="9">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// when the id checkbox is clicked
$('table').delegate('input[name=id]', 'click', function(){

    // set the total at 0
    var totalCost = 0;

    // loop through each checked line
    $('input[name=id]:checked').each(function(){

       // get the input values for this checked row
       var thisRow = $(this).parent(), 
           person = thisRow.find('input[name=name]').val(),
           qty = thisRow.find('input[name=quantity]').val(),
           cost = thisRow.find('input[name=cost]').val();

       // get total
       var lineCost = cost * qty;

       // add to the grand total 
       totalCost+=parseFloat(lineCost);

    });

    // output the total cost
    $('#output').empty().append(totalCost);

});
```

Should I be building an array or an object? I basically just need to get all names that have been checked, and show a grand total for each. I just need a point in the right direction.

Comment: What are you aiming for? Performance? Shortest amount of code? Lot of different ways you could go about doing it, but what are you aiming for?

Comment: Good question, there won't be a ton of checkboxes so it shouldn't be too heavy. I guess code readability would be something to shoot for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/vdunm/2/

It basically just builds an object with the individually grouped totals.

Answer (score 1):

You should be building an object, as long as there's no real sorting required.

Right after your totals you can have these lines:

```
totalCost += parseFloat(lineCost);

if(totals[person] == null) {
    totals[person] = 0;
}

totals[person] += totalCost;
```

You would also need to define:

```
var totals = {};
```

That would go above your loop.